# removing previous image

Tags: actionscript-3

Whats a better way to remove an old image or an image that is not there at all?

I am working with this XML slideshow and I have tweaked it the way I want, except the first image that loads doesn't disappear. How can I make this statement better? I've tried `if (previous || imgHolder.numChildren > 0 )` as well and didn't work. Any help?

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import com.greensock.*;
    import com.greensock.loading.*;
    import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;
    import com.greensock.loading.display.*;


    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {

        var xml:XMLLoader;
        var images:Array;
        var current:int = 0;
        var previous:Number;


        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }

        private function init()
        {
            LoaderMax.activate([ImageLoader]);
            xml = new XMLLoader("xml/gallery.xml",{name:"loader",onComplete:onXmlLoaded});
            xml.load();
        }

        function onXmlLoaded(e:LoaderEvent)
        {
            images = LoaderMax.getContent("loader");
            nextImage(); //nextImage can use image var

        }

        private function nextImage()
        {
            TweenLite.from(images[current],1,{alpha:0, onStart:currentImage, onComplete: updateImage});
        }

        private function currentImage():void
        {
            imgHolder.addChild(images[current]);
        }

        private function updateImage()
        {
            if (previous)
            {
                imgHolder.removeChild(images[previous]);
            }
            previous = current;

            if (current < images.length - 1)
            {
                current++;
            } else
            {
                current = 0;
            }

            TweenLite.delayedCall(2, nextImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manipulate the contents of the Array to keep track of your current and previous slide index. The first in the Array is your current slide and the last is the previous slide. Like you suggested a `numChildren` check on your `imgHolder` is a good way to check if there is something to remove.

```
private function nextImage() : void
{
    TweenLite.from(images[0], 1 , {alpha:0, onStart:currentImage, onComplete:updateImage});
}

private function currentImage():void
{
    imgHolder.addChild(images[0]);
}

private function updateImage() : void
{

    if(imgHolder.numChildren > 1)
    {
        imgHolder.removeChild(images[images.length-1]);
    }

    images.push(images.shift());

    TweenLite.delayedCall(2, nextImage);
}
```

Comment: Ok that actually worked fine. What scares me is I am not really sure how you came to this fix. I am still a noob and also never used the shift method. I'll have to find a way to manipulate next and prev buttons from this. Thanks again.

Comment: I thought it was just the update sequence you needed. If you need any help, just post another question and someone will definitly help you out.

Comment: Yea the update was it thanks. I do have a question for you though. Correct me on my bad math please but if I have 8 images then images.length - 1 would be 7. Why does this get rid of the first image? It works but I would like to know how if you can explain?

Comment: Because we keep track of the currentImage with the Array, we know the last index is the one of the previous image. And since Arrays are zero based, `images.length-1` is the index of the last image.